# How derefencing of a nullptr giving back the correct object?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have been trying to implement a singleton class in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton {
private:
static Singleton* singleton;
public:
static Singleton& Get() {
    return *singleton;
}
static void display() {
    cout << "Hello world\n";
}
};

Singleton* Singleton::singleton = nullptr;
int main() {
Singleton::Get().display();
return 0 ;
}
```

the program works fine.
Can anyone please help me understand how dereferencing a nullptr, is giving back the object reference in 'Get' function of the class.

Comment: It probably seems to work because `display` is *also* a static member function. It's still [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) though, since you're dereferencing a null pointer. Unfortunately, one of the possibilities of UB is that things *seems* to work.

Comment: Unrelated: [A better way to write a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301).

Comment: Even after making 'display' non-static , the program works.

Comment: The given code does not check whether any object is correct. Actually C++ provides no means to perform such a check. It is always a programmer's responsibility to ensure that objects being used are in valid state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered by [core language issue 315: Is call of static member function through null pointer undefined?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315)  which says:

> Another instance to consider is that of invoking a member function
>   from a null pointer:
>
> ```
>   struct A { void f () { } };
>   int main ()
>   {
>     A* ap = 0;
>     ap->f ();
>   }
> ```
>
> Which is explicitly noted as undefined in 12.2.2
>   [class.mfct.non-static], even though one could argue that since f() is
>   empty, there is no lvalue->rvalue conversion.
>
> **If f is static, however, there seems to be no such rule, and the call
>   is only undefined if the dereference implicit in the -> operator is
>   undefined. IMO it should be.**
>
> Incidentally, another thing that ought to be cleaned up is the
>   inconsistent use of "indirection" and "dereference". We should pick
>   one. (This terminology issue has been broken out as issue 342.)
>
> This is related to [issue 232](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232).

and the response was:

> We agreed the example should be allowed. p->f() is rewritten as (*p).f() according to 8.2.5 [expr.ref]. *p is not an error when p is null unless the lvalue is converted to an rvalue (7.1 [conv.lval]), which it isn't here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that's because everything in `Singleton` is static. Add a data element and do something with it and you'll be more likely to see problems.